# Requests gets only a part of the website source code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape target.com, and it seems to parse only a part of the website without the products(the main part). My code worked perfectly for Walmart, but this website doesn't...

My code:

```
res = requests.get(f'https://www.target.com/s?searchTerm=mask')
    print(res)  # Prints 200
    try: 
      res.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e: 
      print('Connection Error')  # In case the connection fails

    else:
      soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
      print(soup.find_all('li', class_='Col-favj32-0 diyyNr h-padding-a-none h-display-flex', limit = 5))
```

If I print soup.prettify() it prints a part of the website, without the products...
I know it will work with Selenium, and I tried, but need it to work without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data about products you see on the page is loaded from external URL. You can use `requests`/`json` modules to load this data.

For example:

```
import json
import requests


kw = 'mask'
url = 'https://redsky.target.com/v2/plp/search/?channel=web&count=96&keyword={kw}&offset=0&pricing_store_id=3991&key=ff457966e64d5e877fdbad070f276d18ecec4a01'

data =  requests.get(url.format(kw=kw)).json()

# uncomment this to print all data;
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# print some data to screen
for i in data['search_response']['items']['Item']:
    print('{:<60} {}'.format(i['title'], i['price']['formatted_current_price']))
```

Prints:

```
2pk Adult Fabric Face Mask                                   $4.00
ICU Non Medical Face Mask 20ct                               $15.99
Adult 2pk Fabric Face Mask - Colors May Vary                 $5.00
Kids&#39; 2pk Fabric Face Masks - Colors May Vary            $5.00
Intco Non-medical Disposable Face Mask - 10ct                $8.99
Cetaphil Pro Derma Control Purifying Clay Mask - 3oz         $15.99
Jurassic World Velociraptor "Blue" Chomp 'N Roar Mask        $29.99
Pixi DetoxifEYE Facial Treatment - 60ct                      $24.00

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved me hours or even days of research just in 10 minutes :D

Comment: Btw, I want to scrape bestbuy.com too, and it returns 403, also doesnt have any json that parses the products(yes I searched a lot). Can you give me any hints?

Comment: @MercifulSory 403 means unauthorized requests. It can happen because of multiple reasons. 403 is sent when your ip doesn't match location they allow, or you have not logged in where they want you to log in. Try to open that in browser, see how request is being made with the headers and check if you have missed anything. If it is because of location, you should use proxy servers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't scrape elements from beautiful soup which are not there. Check for source of the page and see for yourself if the data you're searching for exists in the page. Apparently, it is not there. It is being rendered by javascript.

In your case, it looks like the site is making **XHR Requests** to an **API** and using the response of that data to display. To view the API, go to inspect elements and look at the **Network Tab**. You'll see section called **XHR**. From there, you can search for data you're intending to grab and make request to that api url instead.

@Andrej is right and discovered the API URL the same way.